# how to access a function in a jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

im using this youtube api jquery plugin that i found(the code is located here):

http://pastie.org/4227879

in my index.html i write this code to access the plugin, thiers a function on line 124 in the plugin that i want to use called `seekTo`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#player').youTubeEmbed({
        video :"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NcJ_63z-mA",
        width: 500,
        // access seekTo here i.e. seekTo(123, true)
        });
```

would that be possible? thanks :))

Comment: Without modifying the plugin, no you can't access that other than selecting the element that the plugin adds to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the plugin would be the easiest way to go. Just add a data value to the `originalDiv`.

```
$(elements.originalDiv).data("youTubeEmbed",elements);
return elements.originalDiv;
```

Now, you can access it with:

```
$("#player").data("youTubeEmbed").elements.player.seekTo(123,true);
```